# Disable Abilty to Change BlackBerry Device Time

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

My customer requires an uregent answer on whether I can prevent users from changing the device time on the BlackBerry.

Can this be done either through code or through BES policy?  Through the code would be preferrable.

I'm using the plug-in gor Eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant be done as far as I know.  If I ever get a better answer I will post it.